# SQL Server database creates multiple process on one server and not another

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two SQL Server 1 (QA) and 1 (PROD).

I noticed that in the QA database, when executing a query from C# code that it uses only 1 thread/connection/process.

In the PROD database, the same C# code is executed but the SQL Monitor shows it creates 20+ connections / threads. Most of the threads show up as `SUSPENDED` then all goes away when the code finishes.

Could this be a memory / resource issue?

To test this I just changed the connection string in the C# code to point to the PROD database. So I have ruled out that it is a web server or the server that the code is running on.

here is the c# code that gets executed:

```
var db = new dbcontext();

var results = (from I in db.mytable
               select I).tolist();
```

Comment: Different settings for connection pooling?

Comment: If this were better formulated and reproducible, we could either 1) answer it for you here, or 2) migrate it to DBA.SE if it was indeed, not a programming question.

Comment: Perhaps your production server is to run in parallel but your QA one is not. Compare the SQL Server settings, particularly max degree of parallelism.

Comment: connectionStrings are the same just different servername.  Ill check the max degree and see if that is it. Max degree is set the same on both server. It is set to 0. PROD has 1.6 GB available space and QA has 6.8 GB available space. Could that cause issues?

Comment: the PROD has 4 CPU and the QA has 1 CPU.  Does that matter?

Comment: Yep; that matters.  What's happening is that SQL Server knows that it can't parallelize on QA, so it's generating an execution plan with all single-threaded operators.  On Production, it's generating a parallel plan (probably on multiple operators).  The symptoms you are describing are normal, and may not be a cause for concern.